# Conditional format using the IF function

Tags: conditional-formatting

I'm trying to use a conditional format using the IF function to determine if a value needs a dropdown menu.

Example: if A1=book, then provides a list of authors to choose from; the same if A1=car, then provide a list of automobile brands and so on for other options.

At the moment I'll have to use the formula in different columns:

Example: Column B will have this formula `=IF(A1="books", "Required","")` and then add Conditional Format with a list of authors to choose from. Column C will have the formula `=IF(A1="car", "Required","")` then add Conditional Format with a list of automobile brands.

If there any way to have everything in one column that would be very helpful.

I would really appreciate any help on the subject.